# Does Flurry Analytics for iOS/Android/Blackberry work when offline?

Tags: mobile, analytics, flurry

Flurry Analytics tracks analytics for mobile devices, similar to Google Analytics.
However, we cannot find technical information regarding this question:
Does Flurry tracks analytics when users are offline, then posts them when users come back online?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.  Flurry will track data from offline sessions, save it to persistent storage on the phone and forward it on to the server during the next session with network access.

Comment: wondering if anyone has tested this to figure out of if there is a  limit to the size of queued events when the phone is offline?

Comment: Yes, there is a limit.  I think it varies by platform, but something like 200KB.

Comment: @DaveL. it means we have to save the sending data inside our preferences or DB for sending the data when internet comes.
can flury save the data in send it in session goes online

Comment: @Karmarshad No, the Flurry SDK will handle that for you.

Comment: @DaveL. yes you are right , i mailed to flury support.they said flury will handle this by default.

Comment: Does this also work with javascript API? (for for example cordova / phonegap applications)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, for which you should refer to the direct FAQ link by flurry [HERE](https://goo.gl/aRLFwb)