# How long does Flurry cache data for offline devices?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, analytics, flurry

I'm wondering how long Flurry keeps data about previous sessions when the (Android or iOS) device is offline.

[Flurry's FAQ](https://help.flurry.com/analytics-faq-for-flurry$analytics-whathappensif) makes it seem like session data is kept until it can sent to Flurry servers, I quote:

> What happens if a user uses my application while they are offline? Will you still get that data?

> Yes, Flurry will receive a user’s offline session information the next time they open the application and are online. At that point they will transmit that information to us. The data will be stored locally on the user’s device until it is sent to us.

I also found [this very related question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096629/does-flurry-analytics-for-ios-android-blackberry-work-when-offline), but it's very old and I believe things have probably changed since then. There's a comment in there that seems to indicate the cache size is "around 200KB" but that seems anecdotal. I linked that here just for reference.

Has anybody tested this recently and/or know more information about this? Thanks!